# Collect all User Inputs in Android

Tags: android, user-input, keylistener, keystroke

Hi im writing a new Android program to collect all user inputs, the EditText values (no password, no sensitive informations) from my application and other apps. How to achieve this? Is there any broadcast receivers or observers in Android which listens the keyboard keystrokes?? Any help is appreciated...

**EDIT:- for better understanding:** Access and process the User Input EditText values. keyboard apps already collect all input Information and they process the words to provide better suggestion. Is there any inbuilt API or Accessibility API for this??

Thank You.

Comment: just use a key listener. It depends what context they are typing in

Comment: I need it to work on both mine and other apps..Can u show some example? Do i need to run any service?

Comment: That would basically be a key-logger and I guess there are security restrictions which disallow this.

Comment: Even the swiftkey collects all user information (have no intention to create a keyboard app)!!

Comment: Oh, I see. I have to agree with Dominic. Why are you trying to key log?

Comment: I plan to develop an app which collect all user inputs, process it and to generate some word patterns...

Comment: This is way too sparse of a question, narrow your question down to pieces and then work on each piece, if its even possible.. Which I highly doubt.

Comment: The reason a keyboard works is because it actually takes the input, so reading it is within the contextual usage of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is going to prevent you from peeking in on other processes -- that kind of security is one of the reasons Android runs every package in its own process and requires intents or other managed forms of inter-process communication.

I know you said that you're not interested in building a keyboard app, but I suspect an InputMethodEditor may be the only legitimate way to accomplish this.